# loop on a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can we run a loop on a function in javascript, so that the function executes several times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you tired of using standard like (IF, WHILE), here is the another way of doing.. :)

you can use setTimeOut and clearTimeOut to execute functions in a certain interval. If you want to execute an function for a specific number of times, you still can acheive it by incrementing index and clearTimeOut as soon as your index reaches to certain point.

> setTimeout() - executes a code some time in the future
>
> clearTimeout() - cancels the setTimeout()

example from w3schools

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=0;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
c=c+1;
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  timedCount();
  }
}

function stopCount()
{
clearTimeout(t);
timer_is_on=0;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onClick="doTimer()">
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="button" value="Stop count!" onClick="stopCount()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use a **[for](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)** loop and a **[while](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp)** loop in javascript

```
for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    MyFunc();
}
```

Where the variable 'i' is the number of times it needs to run

Comment: @KP At the time I didnt have the code in there but the for and while are links to code on w3schools. I guess they didnt notice that so I added the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Learn basic JavaScript at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp). It's well worth the effort - it won't take long.

Comment: Correction.  It will take long.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) //Loop 10 times
{
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function is called `f`.

```
function f()
{
    ...
}
```

Here is a Javascript loop that will run your function 10 times.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
    f();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to iterate (functionaly) over a function, that is also
optimised (using loop unrolling), on average it will be up to `16` times **faster**

(adapted from a functional lib of mine use as you wish)

```
function iterate( F, i0, i1, F0 )
{
    if ( i0 > i1 ) return F0;
    else if ( i0 === i1 ) { F(i0, F0, i0, i1); return F0; }
    var l=i1-i0+1, i, k, r=l&15, q=r&1;
    if ( q ) F(i0, F0, i0, i1);
    for (i=q; i<r; i+=2)
    { 
        k = i0+i;
        F(  k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
    }
    for (i=r; i<l; i+=16)
    {
        k = i0+i;
        F(  k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
        F(++k, F0, i0, i1);
    }
    return F0;
}
```

use example:

```
function iterated(i, a, i0, i1)
{
     console.log([i, i0, i1]);
     a.push(i);
}
var a = iterate(iterated, 0, 9, []); // optionaly one can pass a parameter in the iterator
console.log(a);
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 9]
[1, 0, 9]
[2, 0, 9]
[3, 0, 9]
[4, 0, 9]
[5, 0, 9]
[6, 0, 9]
[7, 0, 9]
[8, 0, 9]
[9, 0, 9]

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```